# Пропорциональное масштабирование окна

Tags: wpf

Здравствуйте. Собственно сабж.

Как вариант реализации:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged_1(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
     this.Height = this.Width;
}
```

Но! При масштабировании окно мигает. Возможно (даже скорее всего) есть какое-то свойтво (флаг пропорционального ресайза) для реализации данной задачи - подскажите, пожалуйста.
P.S. походы по msdn не помогли... =(

Answer (score 1):

Давайте реализуем сохранение aspect ratio в виде attached behavior, чтобы не вмешиваться в код окна, а просто навесить его «со стороны».

Код окна при этом будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowAspectRatio.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowAspectRatio"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <!-- параметр AspectRatio можно и не указывать -->
        <local:WindowAspectRatioBehavior AspectRatio="3"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid Background="Azure"/>
</Window>
```

(для поддержки behaviours нужно подключить сборку System.Windows.Interactivity).

Реализацию поведения (behaviour) отделим от логики. (Логику можно повторно использовать где-то ещё.)

Итак, вот `WindowAspectRatioBehavior`:

```
class WindowAspectRatioBehavior : Behavior<Window> // только для целого окна
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        // пробуем навеситься сразу...
        var hwnd = TryGetHwndSource(AssociatedObject);
        if (hwnd != null)
            keeper = new AspectRatioKeeper(hwnd, double.IsNaN(AspectRatio) ?
                        default(double?) : AspectRatio);
        else
            AssociatedObject.SourceInitialized += OnSourceInitialized;
        // если у окна ещё нету HWND, подождём, пока появится
    }

    void OnSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // опять пробуем навеситься
        var hwnd = TryGetHwndSource(AssociatedObject);
        if (hwnd != null)
            keeper = new AspectRatioKeeper(hwnd, double.IsNaN(AspectRatio) ?
                        default(double?) : AspectRatio);
        AssociatedObject.SourceInitialized -= OnSourceInitialized;
    }

    static HwndSource TryGetHwndSource(Window w)
    {
        return (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(w);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SourceInitialized -= OnSourceInitialized;
        if (keeper != null)
            keeper.Dispose();
        keeper = null;
    }

    public double AspectRatio
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AspectRatioProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AspectRatioProperty, value); }
    }

    // обыкновенное dependency property. при изменении значения вызываем
    // функцию OnAspectChanged. По умолчанию NaN, что означает
    // пользоваться aspect ratio, как у окна на момент навешивания
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AspectRatioProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AspectRatio", typeof(double), typeof(WindowAspectRatioBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(double.NaN, (o, args) =>
                ((WindowAspectRatioBehavior)o).OnAspectChanged()));

    void OnAspectChanged()
    {
        var ratio = AspectRatio;
        // если мы уже поддерживаем размер, нам нужно его переустановить
        if (keeper != null && !double.IsNaN(ratio))
            keeper.SetAspectRatio(ratio);
    }

    AspectRatioKeeper keeper;
}
```

Вся логика пересчёта лежит в `AspectRatioKeeper`'е. Здесь нам придётся спуститься на нижний уровень, к оконной процедуре, и серьёзно поиспользовать P/Invoke.

```
class AspectRatioKeeper : IDisposable
{
    // хэндл окна, за которым мы следим
    HwndSource hwnd;

    // если forceRatio == null, мы запоминаем начальное состояние и поддерживаем его
    public AspectRatioKeeper(HwndSource hwnd, double? forceRatio)
    {
        this.hwnd = hwnd;
        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd.Handle, out rect);
        _aspectRatio = forceRatio ?? ((double)rect.Height / rect.Width);
        if (forceRatio.HasValue)
            EnsureAspectRatio(rect.Width, rect.Height);
        hwnd.AddHook(DragHook);
    }

    public void SetAspectRatio(double ratio)
    {
        _aspectRatio = ratio;
        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd.Handle, out rect);
        EnsureAspectRatio(rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }

    void EnsureAspectRatio(int w, int h)
    {
        EnsureAspectRatioValue(ref w, ref h, true);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, -1, -1, w, h,
                     SWP.NOACTIVATE | SWP.NOMOVE | SWP.NOSENDCHANGING);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        hwnd.RemoveHook(DragHook);
    }

    // это наш хук, следим за изменениями размеров окна
    IntPtr DragHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch ((WM)msg)
        {
        case WM.WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
            {
                // новый размер и позиция окна
                WINDOWPOS pos =
                    (WINDOWPOS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(WINDOWPOS));

                if ((pos.flags & (int)SWP.NOMOVE) != 0)
                    return IntPtr.Zero;

                // Здесь была проверка, является ли окно с данным хэндлом
                // действительно WPF-окном. Но она по идее не нужна.

                // если мы ещё не знаем, меняем мы высоту или ширину, определим это
                if (!_adjustingHeight.HasValue)
                {
                    Point p = GetMousePosition();

                    // считаем расстояния позиции мыши от краёв окна
                    double mouseFromLeft = Math.Abs(p.X - pos.x),
                           mouseFromRight = Math.Abs(p.X - pos.x - pos.cx),
                           mouseFromTop = Math.Abs(p.Y - pos.y),
                           mouseFromBottom = Math.Abs(p.Y - pos.y - pos.cy);

                    double diffWidth = Math.Min(mouseFromLeft, mouseFromRight),
                           diffHeight = Math.Min(mouseFromTop, mouseFromBottom);

                    // похоже, мы меняем высоту. или ширину. запомним это.
                    _adjustingHeight = diffHeight < diffWidth;
                }

                EnsureAspectRatioValue(ref pos.cx, ref pos.cy, _adjustingHeight.Value);

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(pos, lParam, true);
                handled = true;
            }
            break;
        case WM.EXITSIZEMOVE:
            // мы закончили перетаскивание, в следующий раз направление придётся
            // определять заново
            _adjustingHeight = null;
            break;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    // просто пересчёт численного значения высоты и ширины, с учётом их отношения
    // и максимального/минимального системного значений
    void EnsureAspectRatioValue(ref int w, ref int h, bool tryKeepWidth)
    {
        if (tryKeepWidth)
            w = (int)(h / _aspectRatio); // adjusting height to width change
        else
            h = (int)(w * _aspectRatio); // adjusting width to heigth change

        if (w > maxw)
        {
            w = (int)maxw;
            h = (int)(w * _aspectRatio);
        }
        else if (w < minw)
        {
            w = (int)minw;
            h = (int)(w * _aspectRatio);
        }

        if (h > maxh)
        {
            h = (int)maxh;
            w = (int)(h / _aspectRatio);
        }
        else if (h < minh)
        {
            h = (int)minh;
            w = (int)(h / _aspectRatio);
        }
    }

    double _aspectRatio;
    bool? _adjustingHeight = null;
    double minh = SystemParameters.MinimumWindowHeight,
           minw = SystemParameters.MinimumWindowWidth,
           maxh = SystemParameters.MaximumWindowTrackHeight,
           maxw = SystemParameters.MaximumWindowTrackWidth;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // дальше будет просто импорт функция WinAPI и определение структур данных
    // большая часть взята с сайта pinvoke.net

    enum WM
    {
        WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046,
        EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232,
    }

    [Flags]
    enum SWP : uint
    {
        ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,
        DEFERERASE = 0x2000,
        DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,
        FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,
        HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,
        NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,
        NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,
        NOMOVE = 0x0002,
        NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,
        NOREDRAW = 0x0008,
        NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,
        NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,
        NOSIZE = 0x0001,
        NOZORDER = 0x0004,
        SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct WINDOWPOS
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public IntPtr hwndInsertAfter;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
        public int flags;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
        public int Height { get { return Bottom - Top; } }
        public int Width { get { return Right - Left; } }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT rect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(
        IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
        int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SWP uFlags);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Win32Point
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
    };

    static Point GetMousePosition() // mouse position relative to screen
    {
        Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
        return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
    }
}
```

---

Код во многом основан на [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959611/276994).